# Semi-humorous Asian (Indian?) live-action zombie film where a slacker attempts to survive a zombie apocalypse. Zombies cured with skin care products

Tags: story-identification, movie, zombie

I think I watched this on Netflix a few years ago, within the last five years, although it could be older. I don't think the film was in English, and part of me wants to say it was in an Asian language like Malaysian or Thai with subtitles. The protagonist is a slacker who drives a scooter (I think he's a delivery guy?) and has a girlfriend who is a teacher. I think the film opens with them and two of their other friends up on an elevated spot by their car, drinking beer and talking, maybe in relation to a birthday. I think they run into a sick animal of some sort, which is implied to be the vector of the zombie disease. There's also an indication of infidelity, although I think it relates to the other two characters rather than the protagonist and his girlfriend. In general, the protagonist is shown to be a bit of a loser, including at least one incident where he's pulled aside by local police, I think for not wearing the proper helmet on his scooter.

The next day, the zombies start popping up, and the protagonist fights his way to the school to rescue the girlfriend, I think after donning cricket pads and grabbing a cricket bat to fight with. As he heads in, there's at least one scene where his scooter starts to die on him and he frantically has to restart it to get away from the zombies, and I think there's a scene where he runs into the policeman from before who is more interested in citing him for the helmet than dealing with the zombies. How serious the zombie infestation kind of pinballs back and forth, with most scenes showing the protagonist easily fending off the stumbling zombies, but also plenty of gore and torn-up bodies including lost limbs. At the school, the protagonist learns fends off zombified kids, and I think learns that he's too late and she's already been turned.

Somewhere in between, the girl from the scene where they were drinking is attending a seminar being done by a multi-level marketing guy who promises immense wealth (as shown by having expensive cars and a house) by selling his skin-care products. It's clear that this girl has bought into it hook, line, and sinker, but it's clear to the viewer that this is an outright scam. One of those events gets attacked and the scam guy tries to sacrifice everyone else to save his own skin, only to fail.

The climax of the film has the protagonist and some of his friends (and I think the police officer from before?) holed up in a parking garage where there's a pallet of the skin care products, I think also with the zombified girlfriend locked away in an adjacent room. In the course of an attack, one of the containers of skin care products is grabbed and thrown at the zombie and it miraculously reverses the infection. What follows is the characters driving down the road and squirting the zombies with the skin care product, instantly curing them, cue the happy ending.

It didn't look like an independent film, having decent camera work, lighting and sound. The special effects were a bit lackluster, with the zombie makeup basically involving making the skin pale, contact lenses, and some minor blood and injury prosthetics. My suspicion is that it's from an actual movie studio, just not up to Hollywood levels, probably one in the country of the language used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might this be *[KL Zombi](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3132450/)* (2013)...?

> Tells the tale of slacker, Nipis who becomes a reluctant hero when a zombie outbreak robs him of the only life he knows.

It's a Malaysian film, and the opening scene does match your description, with a group of friends meeting up on an elevated spot near a parked car, and one of them getting bitten by what was presumably an infected dog.

Comment: I was just about to post I found it. :)